# Implementing COUNTIF function with a changing string criterion

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I have a long list of business licenses in Excel. I have a separate list of all the *unique* names of the licenses and I want to use a `COUNTIF` function to count how many times each license comes from the long list.

Now, I don't want to use `COUNTIF` with a different string criterion for each license name, it will be too time consuming. Is there a way for me to send a string in this case the name of the license that is stored in another cell into the function `COUNTIF` to serve as the criterion? Then click and drag it down the list to get a total count of each license.

The screenshot shows the hypothetical:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Comment: You seem to be looking for an expression like `=COUNTIF($F$2:$F$50976;F50982)`. Notice the dollar signs **$** - the search range is set to the ABSOLUTE address of the range, and the search cell is set to the RELATIVE address. This will allow you to specify the correct addresses for each next cell when stretching the formula down.

Comment: In addition, you could solve this problem very simply if you select the entire range `F1:F50976` and use the [**Insert > PivotTable**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) command

Comment: The coordinates of the cell with the criteria, should not be in quotes

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the pivot table which is probably your best bet, the screen cap below demonstrating a combination of the UNIQUE function to get a list of all the different license type and then COUNTIFS against that is an option.

When you enter UNIQUE in the first cell it will create the entire list immediately.

[image]

But be careful with UNIQUE if there is not enough space under the cell you add it to you will get a #SPILL error. (example below)

[image]

Comment: You will need to be a Microsoft 365 subscriber to make use of the `=UNIQUE()` worksheet function. Without this you will need to generate your own list of licenses and the use either `=COUNTIF()` or `=COUNTIFS()` (doesn't matter which if only counting against a single criterion). Useful check on integrity of your own list of licenses is to sum counts by license and check it matches total of licenses.